# Pycharm Kivy installation windows 11

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, kivy, windows-11

I am having problems installing kivy on my pycharm.
Help please

I tried it in cmd: it says it can’t find a version that satisfies requirements.

Is there a version for win11 yet?
Or it is yet to be released?

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you following these [instructions](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-kivy)?

Comment: What version of Python do you have installed? According to kivy release notes "Currently supported Python versions are 3.7-3.11".